# What's the difference in usage between "annoyed at", "annoyed with", and "annoyed by"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-with

When is it appropriate to use *annoyed at*? Can I say I'm *annoyed at* you or should it be *annoyed with* you? What about *annoyed by*?

I've read somewhere that *annoyed with* is for people and *annoyed at* is for the rest but I haven't been able to find a link to a supporting document/textbook.

Comment: It seems to me that "by" is more commonly used for something that normally/always annoys, as opposed to something that is currently annoying: "I am annoyed by your loud music" means "when you play your music too loudly, I get annoyed", as opposed "I am annoyed at your loud music". It is not a hard and fast rule at all...substitute "get" for "am" in the above examples, for example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am annoyed *by* a specific behavior.

I am annoyed *with* the person who's doing it.

I am annoyed *at* a requirement.

Comment: "Annoyed at" exists actually...

Comment: @Alenanno: Such as?

Comment: @SLaks: "_he was annoyed at being woken up so early_", taken from my NOAD. Or the third example on the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/annoyed): "_I bet she was annoyed at having to write it out again._"

Comment: Bravo for the edit; this now summarizes my feelings exactly. (Where's the +5 button when you need it?)

Comment: +1: I would rarely say *I'm being annoyed at your daughter,* or *I'm being annoyed with your daughter,* although I might say *I'm being annoyed by your daughter.* So if somebody is doing something annoying, I am *annoyed by* them, although I might also be *annoyed with* them for doing it.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to use *annoyed* as an adjective and you can also use the verb *to annoy*.  I think it helps to consider these forms separately.

First the adjective:

> I am annoyed **by** elephants.
> *Elephants in general annoy me.*
>
> I am annoyed **with** my sister.
> *My sister has done something to annoy me.*
>
> I am annoyed **at** my sister.
> (*identical meaning to with*)

And the verb:

> She is annoying me **by** drumming.
> *by + gerund (action that annoys)*
>
> She is annoying me **with** her drum.
> *with + a noun (thing that annoys)*

*At* is not used with the verb.  In the BNC there are zero occurrences of *annoyed (v.) at* and [67 occurrences](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/x3.asp?xx=1&w11=annoyed.%5Ba*%5D&w12=at&r=) of *annoyed (adj.) at*.

Comment: I perceive a definite difference in meaning between "annoyed with" and "annoyed by".

Comment: As an aside, how did you generate that chart?

Comment: @emragins, it looks like a Google nGrams chart to me. But I agree that it would be more useful to include a link to its source.

Comment: @Martha: Yes it's a nGram Graph... By the way, I don't really agree on the fact that they're interchangeable. It may occur in some cases, I can't be sure of the opposite at the moment, but they don't sound as completely interchangeable.

Comment: @Alennano: Oh, I agree. Like I said, I perceive a definite difference in meaning between "with" and "by", and on the rare occasion I use "at", it too means something slightly different than the other two choices.

Comment: @Martha, I agree with the first comment, there is a difference.  Reading some of the comments on the other question I thought it would be worth trying to clarify the difference between using the verb and adjective.  I think this leads to some of the confusion because you can use *at* with the adjective but not the verb.

Answer (score 1):

In the second sentence there is the potential for two different meanings, when the words *at* and *with* are interchanged:

1. He was annoyed *at* the children. – No ambiguity.
2. He was annoyed *with* the children. – Ambiguous, because it is now unclear as to whether the children were also annoyed.

For those who have English as a second language this could be confusing, because the word *with* is more often used to join nouns.

Answer (score 1):

As one responder has mentioned, "annoyed by" can be used for statements of general truth ("I am annoyed by loud music"), whereas "annoyed with" and "annoyed at" are the result of the target's past behavior: "I am annoyed with/at my sister because of something that she did."

Try this with other similar verbs and adjectives: *frustrated, irritated, angry, happy*. Sometimes "at" works, but "with" always does.